# Adding an application to http://www.domain.com/newapp/

Tags: iis, subdomain

I have a client who needed a new site. I simply pointed his current website to a new folder (new app) in the IIS manager.

Now, he needs access to the old site. How do I his old site to "http://www.domain.com/entire-app-here/"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a virtual directory under the site and point it toward his old stuff, or just copy the old stuff into the ~/entire-app-here/ directory of the new site base.

Answer (score 0):

most apps (php,asp,etc) can be just move it to new folder and it will works.
some apps, you need to edit few config files to make it work.

or you can simply leave the old site where it is.
and redirect / to /new-app

this way, all links to old site will still load perfectly. (good for seo)
and all new user will be redirected to /new-app